# Ion-sfu Flutter SDK not publishing stream

Tags: webrtc

I am working on a WebRTC video platform using Ion-sfu, which has been a really great experience so far, I have the SFU up and running, the AVP to record sessions, and a browser client working beautifully using the Javascript SDK.

Where I am stuck is with getting the Flutter SDK to play ball, I am using the sample code from the Github repo here:

https://github.com/pion/ion-sdk-flutter

The flutter client is connecting to the SFU, I can see the debug logs from the SFU:

[DEBUG] [57][subscriber.go][func1] => ice connection state: connected

I'm also receiving a stream in the Flutter app coming from my Javascript client, which also works flawlessly, so it appears the RTC connection between all the clients and the SFU is healthy.

I am rendering the local stream from ion.LocalStream.getUserMedia() in my flutter app so the stream also seems to be working, it's just not being published when I call await client.publish(localStream);

I am seeing this message in my debug logs:

I/flutter (12711): [ion-sdk-flutter] DEBUG: msg: {"id":0,"error":{"code":500,"message":"no rtc transport exists for this Peer","data":null},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}
I/flutter (12711): [ion-sdk-flutter] ERROR: error: code => 500, message => no rtc transport exists for this Peer

I am on the Flutter dev channel.

I have been hitting my head on this for some time now so if anybody has had experience using this and could point me in the right direction that would be a great help!

Comment: Hey, Did you found any solution? I am also facing the same issue after adding a stun configuration